# PySide2 QQuickWidget hover effects not working

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyside2

I am trying to create a PieMenu in a QtWidgets application and that would mean I need to use QQuickWidget to display the QQuick component.

When using PySide2 all the hover effects and animations are disabled but the menu clicking appears to be working. I tried the same code in C++ Qt and it works correctly.

Is this a limitation in PySide2 or am I supposed to do it differently?

here's my code:

mainwindow.h

```cpp
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtQuickWidgets/QQuickWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
public slots:
    void menuTriggered();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QQuickWidget *view;
    QQuickItem *object;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QCursor>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->view = new QQuickWidget(this);
    view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    view->setClearColor(Qt::transparent);
    view->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint|Qt::Tool|Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
    view->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    view->setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground);
    view->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents);
    view->setStyleSheet("background:transparent; border:none; color:white;");
    view->hide();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::menuTriggered()
{
    view->move(QCursor::pos());
    view->show();
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(object, "openMenu");
}
```

main.qml

```js
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Extras 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4

Item {
    id: item1
    width: pieMenu.width+50
    height: pieMenu.height+80

    function openMenu(){
        pieMenu.popup(width/2,height/2)
    }

    PieMenu {
        id: pieMenu
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenterOffset: 0
        height:width
        objectName: "pieMenu"
        triggerMode: TriggerMode.TriggerOnPress
        MenuItem {
            text: "Action 1"
            onTriggered: print("Action 1")
        }
        MenuItem {
            text: "Action 2"
            onTriggered: print("Action 2")
        }
        MenuItem {
            text: "Action 3"
            onTriggered: print("Action 3")
        }
    }
}
```

the problem code in python:

```py
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PySide2.QtQuickWidgets import QQuickWidget


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        ...
        ...
        self.view = QQuickWidget(self)
        self.view.setSource(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile("main.qml"))
        self.view.setClearColor(QtCore.Qt.transparent)
        self.view.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.view.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground)
        self.view.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint |
                                 QtCore.Qt.Tool | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.object = self.view.rootObject()
        self.object.visibilityChanged.connect(self.menuTriggered)

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def menuTriggered(self):
        self.view.move(QtGui.QCursor.pos())
        self.view.show()
        QtCore.QMetaObject.invokeMethod(self.object, "openMenu")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    mainwindow = MainWindow()
    mainwindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Have you already tried using the approach suggested in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58041521/pyside2-composite-widget-hover-effect)?

Comment: I don't think that answer applies in my case, I am not trying to manually animate anything from the QWidget side.